# Jms app could not refesh connection with ibm mq

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, websphere-8

I have Ibm mq server and i trying to connect to to it from my application. My application is deployed on the websphere 8.5.5 Im using to connect to ibm mq server ibm implementation (MQQueueConnectionFactory) with spring (JmsTemplate).

When I deploy it on tomcat and i am trying to connect to remote ibm mq server - there is no problem . I can sand and receive information form queue, but when i deploy application on websphere i have this exception:

```
[1395,maxpri=10]] c.c.b.o.s.impl.StandardSequencer : [ - default - ] Server 1,001 has acquired/renewed the lock on sequencer 1,001. [sequencer:169] [Object=null, Object=null, Object=null, userid=null, uuid=null]

[10/12/18 10:15:59:977 UTC] 000062ea SystemOut O 2018-10-12 10:15:59.977 ERROR 774 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'QUeueTest' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=70, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException[null],3=GeneratedConstructorAccessor678.newInstance]
```

I think that the problematic part are lbires but i have know idea how to fix it.
So I want to use activemq implementation as a client to connect to ibm mq server.
It is possible ?
Thank You for any answer.

Comment: You can not use activemq to connect as a client to IBM MQ. You should download the IBM MQ Resource Adaptor, google `MQC8` for MQ v8.0, `MQC9` for MQ v9.0, or `MQC91` for MQ v9.1. Once you have clicked the link to access Fixcentral get the file with a name like v9.1's `9.1.0.0-IBM-MQ-Java-InstallRA`

Comment: 1. Please post the full stack trace. 3. Are you using BINDINGS or CLIENT mode? 3. Did you follow the instructions from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q132480_.htm ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem .

The application was deployed on websphere server . I deployed it with all jar without scope provided. It was mistake . When app is on server needs only wmq.jmsra jars.

```
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>

        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>

        <version>9.0.4.0</version>

        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/wmq.jmsra -->

    <dependency>

        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>

        <artifactId>wmq.jmsra</artifactId>

        <version>9.0.4.0</version>

        <type>rar</type>

        <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>
```

Thank You for help.

Comment: WAS comes with IBM MQ Resource Adapter included, there should be no need to deploy any IBM MQ jars along with your application.